# How to organize a Windows Forms applications in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

This is somewhat silly, but it's been bugging me. I'm developing a Windows Forms application, and I'm using lots of data sources. When I create them, they're automatically placed in the root of my project. For the sake of organization, I've created a `DataSources` subdirectory and moved them in there.

The trouble is that when I move the .xsd files from the root my the `DataSources` directory, the project references break and I need to update the designer file in a few places. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new datasources, just create them in the desired subdirectory.  That is right click on the subdirectory and create new component there.

For your existing files I believe the location of file is indicated in: xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="your.xsd"
You should be able the change to add path relative to project, something like: xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../subdir/shiporder.xsd"> or perhaps just: xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="subdir/shiporder.xsd">

I hope this helps